# Returning the Day of a string date in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python string date and I want to return the day, year, month of that string. Such as Year = 2020 , Month = 05

```
dteStartDate ='05/01/2020'
dteStartDate.day
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you do any research on how to convert a string to a (date) object that has a `.date` attribute?

Comment: Yes I tried to use the strfttime but it said that it str has no attribute

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime.datetime`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> start_date = datetime.strptime('05/01/2020', '%m/%d/%Y')
>>> start_date.day, start_date.year, start_date.month
(1, 2020, 5)
```

Comment: I get an error module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: Did you do `from datetime import datetime` like in the code I pasted above, or just `import datetime`?  If you just did `import datetime` then you need to use `datetime.datetime.strptime` (to access the `strptime` method of the `datetime` class in the `datetime` module).